# Main books on the relationship between religion and science

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-religion

I have had the book "History of the Conflict between Religion and Science" by John Willian Draper for a while.  I really liked certain sections of it highlighting the sharp contrast between the old view and the new view (try Nature of the World and the Age of the Earth).  But recently, I came upon books that treated this topic in a more comprehensive and reconciliatory way (describing different models of relationship between religion and science).  I have started reading the works of Ian Barbour (esp. Religion and Science).  I also found the small book "Rocks of Ages" by Stephen Jay Gould very helpful.  But since I still regard myself a beginner in this vast topic, I was wondering if someone with more experience can suggest a reading list starting from the most seminal books on this topic.

Comment: See [John Hedley Brooke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hedley_Brooke)'s books as well as [Peter Harrison (historian)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Harrison_(historian))'s ones.